# Insert parameter value into $evalGlobal in GAMS

Tags: gams-math

Consider the following $SetGlobal:

```
$setglobal Path MyPath
```

I use the following code to finding the numbers of characters in 'MyPath':

```
set Length /%Path%/;
Parameter report(Length,*);

report(Length,'length')   = Length.len ;
```

Thereafter, I want to insert this value (6 in this case) into a $evalGlobal, so I have the following $evalGlobal:

```
$evalGlobal ModelLength 6
```

It should be something like this:

```
$evalGlobal ModelLength %Report("MyPath","length")%
```

But that does not work. How do I insert the length from the parameter "report" into $evalGlobal ModelLength?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that `report(Length,'length')   = Length.len ;` is done on execution time, while you try to access the result of this at compile time already in `$evalGlobal ModelLength ...` (see https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_GamsCall.html#UG_GamsCall_TwoPass).

What you want can be achieved using embedded code:

```
$setglobal Path MyPath

scalar l;

$onEmbeddedCode Python:
s = r'%Path%'
gams.set('l', [len(s)])
$offEmbeddedCode l

$evalGlobal ModelLength l
$log %ModelLength%
```

This is probably not straight forward, but it works...